# Query Order By in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-query-builder

How can display thus code in order by in Codeigniter

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <?php


   $query = $this->db->get('drag');

    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
            echo '<li class="ui-state-default" title="'.$row->main_category_id.'" data-id="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->feeld.' <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delbtn" id="dlbtn" data-ids="'.$row->id.'"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></li>';
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [order_by](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#id4) function.

```
$query = $this->db->order_by("id","DESC")->get('drag');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//you can use ASC or DESC 
$this->db->order_by("created_at", "asc")->get->result_array();
```